# How to reload Page automatically

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am new in python.
This is my practice code.

After log in:

1. Determine if the page contains certain keyword
2. If this page contains keyword then execute file.exe from my local machine
3. Refresh Page and do Step1, Step2, Step3. again and again.

After log in, page only reloads twice instead again and again.
I cannot figure out where it goes wrong.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
webdriver_path = 'C:\Python\chromedriver.exe'
options = Options()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=webdriver_path, options=options)
driver.get("www.TestLogin.com") #Here is a LoginPage
driver.find_element_by_id('_userId').send_keys('userid') #Here is account for login
driver.find_element_by_id('_userPass').send_keys('userpass') #Here is password for login
driver.find_element_by_id('btn-login').click()
driver.find_elements_by_id('table-orders')  


import time
time.sleep(3)
driver.refresh()

#Array for keyword
import_searchs = [
     'rose',
     'tulip'
     ]

for i in import_searchs:
    list = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[contains(text(), "' + i + '")]')
    for item in list:
        import os
        os.system('C"\file.exe')
```

Comment: the script seems to have exited after refreshing it once? maybe you should consider put it in a `while True` loop?

Comment: You don't have any statements to make it do things over and over.  You need to write something to make it [loop](https://www.learnpython.org/en/Loops).

Comment: are you sure about this: 'C"\file.exe' ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`while True` works!

[Thank you everybody](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62274170/how-to-reload-page-automatically/62274821#comment110137184_62274170)